# How to return specific key value pairs from this Json readable extract in Python when key value pair is deeply nested?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value

I'd like to return just the 'publishedAt' and 'textOriginal' keys with their corresponding values from this JSON extract:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "etag": "TqGO73Ytj_bpySwt6jCD8RAnUro",
      "id": "UgzgvW_JT_4Kug4UXWJ4AaABAg",
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "snippet": {
        "canReply": true,
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "isPublic": true,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "etag": "n7jYB-lAHmIJG-ipDrm9FelJT4A",
          "id": "UgzgvW_JT_4Kug4UXWJ4AaABAg",
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "snippet": {
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UC8uGHu-pBSxlvzFbJGtXi_A"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8uGHu-pBSxlvzFbJGtXi_A",
            "authorDisplayName": "20K SUBSCRIBERS WITH 0 VIDEOS CHALLENGE",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJz02tLZkXAUE7sEtLjsTDEwekol_vHryOGCCw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "canRate": true,
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "likeCount": 1,
            "publishedAt": "2020-06-06T09:36:04Z",
            "textDisplay": "Nobody:<br /><br />Marques Brownlee: <b>Making everyones quarantines better</b>",
            "textOriginal": "Nobody:\n\nMarques Brownlee: *Making everyones quarantines better*",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T09:36:04Z",
            "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y",
            "viewerRating": "none"
          }
        },
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y"
      }
    },
    {
      "etag": "ODEKntEIgLndsnBMMj2vs0RUKPA",
      "id": "Ugz6iswc5a4XlepgddR4AaABAg",
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "snippet": {
        "canReply": true,
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "isPublic": true,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "etag": "akYunoedzz7BEc8TfojnnPF1H2s",
          "id": "Ugz6iswc5a4XlepgddR4AaABAg",
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "snippet": {
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCqw0-jR0Koo3M_XSJmrxNfA"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqw0-jR0Koo3M_XSJmrxNfA",
            "authorDisplayName": "James Beesley",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJz8LxrdmpXBYaiEEaco2ryN75nKnSpoMF0ZnA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "canRate": true,
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-06-06T09:36:03Z",
            "textDisplay": "God bless America and all the people there, no matter whether white or black. <br />Greetings from an American who living in Germany for years now.",
            "textOriginal": "God bless America and all the people there, no matter whether white or black. \nGreetings from an American who living in Germany for years now.",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T09:36:03Z",
            "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y",
            "viewerRating": "none"
          }
        },
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y"
      }
    },
    {
      "etag": "aVFF8Fke4FmEF42qeDm1WmxnoN0",
      "id": "UgwmHDYufIDNBuqvbnt4AaABAg",
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "snippet": {
        "canReply": true,
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "isPublic": true,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "etag": "6L2tkvTWVmUsAkm2iP3iBJMbans",
          "id": "UgwmHDYufIDNBuqvbnt4AaABAg",
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "snippet": {
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCVYLjLqnqJ8j9ZGb7qQx80Q"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVYLjLqnqJ8j9ZGb7qQx80Q",
            "authorDisplayName": "sgurung18",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwkCqwDrgE8COyarsavX6avm7pLAgfnGv8yiw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "canRate": true,
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-06-06T09:35:16Z",
            "textDisplay": "Awesome to hear you speak up!!!",
            "textOriginal": "Awesome to hear you speak up!!!",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T09:35:16Z",
            "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y",
            "viewerRating": "none"
          }
        },
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y"
      }
    },
    {
      "etag": "M5rTFFe8oMd3R-h6xa59hXeY3eQ",
      "id": "UgwKJ_x0bslWsBZ-GQJ4AaABAg",
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "snippet": {
        "canReply": true,
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "isPublic": true,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "etag": "WflvYd0l7vGiR8RRN6eH5BCBhSw",
          "id": "UgwKJ_x0bslWsBZ-GQJ4AaABAg",
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "snippet": {
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCV9QBJiUgeixQ8Xd2y4f2Pg"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCV9QBJiUgeixQ8Xd2y4f2Pg",
            "authorDisplayName": "Jonathan Bevington",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxBdXHr6iTUgmJ9V4h0qJJz3cx6wiyJ9g61iA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "canRate": true,
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-06-06T09:35:09Z",
            "textDisplay": "We hear you.",
            "textOriginal": "We hear you.",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T09:35:09Z",
            "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y",
            "viewerRating": "none"
          }
        },
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y"
      }
    },
    {
      "etag": "WXqPZ5ucjEqAL56qKfg23_8R1YE",
      "id": "Ugx0HIMaJy6cVBq8aid4AaABAg",
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "snippet": {
        "canReply": true,
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "isPublic": true,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "etag": "7UAPxJd4m6bGmEfwyID9jqSN9x0",
          "id": "Ugx0HIMaJy6cVBq8aid4AaABAg",
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "snippet": {
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCVR6OLvI3hNM4JG2n2VxHjg"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVR6OLvI3hNM4JG2n2VxHjg",
            "authorDisplayName": "Richie M",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyV3S82luSHN3AJQGi4xdeDDMjzYuSYlssjqg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "canRate": true,
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-06-06T09:34:28Z",
            "textDisplay": "Theres Nothing wrong to be Proud of being black or white or Asian and Any other race for that matter....If it makes people smile and better/more competitive in a good way then so be it.But when people get hurt or even Die:( That is truely out or order....Times Need to change because we all Bleed Red....And even if we didn&#39;t all bleed red we Shouldn&#39;t be Hurting Them period!! We All Need to do a little soul searching and learn to value others and Life in general No Matter the Differences And thats including The Beautiful Animals on the land and seas.",
            "textOriginal": "Theres Nothing wrong to be Proud of being black or white or Asian and Any other race for that matter....If it makes people smile and better/more competitive in a good way then so be it.But when people get hurt or even Die:( That is truely out or order....Times Need to change because we all Bleed Red....And even if we didn't all bleed red we Shouldn't be Hurting Them period!! We All Need to do a little soul searching and learn to value others and Life in general No Matter the Differences And thats including The Beautiful Animals on the land and seas.",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T09:34:28Z",
            "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y",
            "viewerRating": "none"
          }
        },
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y"
      }
    },
    {
      "etag": "MPA9crdN-BqLIwSPpBBiypReLbc",
      "id": "UgyGF-xTpQW0oSTgzNx4AaABAg",
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "snippet": {
        "canReply": true,
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "isPublic": true,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "etag": "NIQnOOSBIzO3YNqyveVFWkIXiJU",
          "id": "UgyGF-xTpQW0oSTgzNx4AaABAg",
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "snippet": {
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCozpTdS_0gwux3elr9-Fa9g"
            },
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCozpTdS_0gwux3elr9-Fa9g",
            "authorDisplayName": "Gitesh Dubal",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxoBeh-Bjt9FGhAso37rsXpgXWqG3HpbWXncQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "canRate": true,
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-06-06T09:32:35Z",
            "textDisplay": "Would love to see your parents in video..\ud83d\ude07",
            "textOriginal": "Would love to see your parents in video..\ud83d\ude07",
            "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T09:32:35Z",
            "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y",
            "viewerRating": "none"
          }
        },
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "videoId": "o-_WXXVye3Y"
      }
    },
```

How would you suggest I go about this when the key value pair I'm interested in is nested inside snippet inside topLevelComment inside snippet inside a list contained in items? (Please forgive me if I've got this wrong).

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have to do is to parse json:

```
import json
data = 'your json data here'
parsed_data = json.loads(data)
```

Then you can access the element you are interested in:

```
element = data['first']['second']['third']
```

Where `first, second, third` is the names of keys to access nested data.

If the data is a list, then you could do something like this:

```
import json
d = 'your json data here'
parsed_data = json.loads(d)
items = parsed_data['items']
for publication_data in items:
    print(publication_data['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt'])
    print(publication_data['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py); it allows you to traverse nested json files quite easily.

Key takeaways for usage: if the data is in a list, you access it with a `[]` notation, if it is in a dict, `.` notation comes to play.

For your data, top level key is items, followed by a list, then sub dicts before you get to publishedAt and textOriginal. So pseudocode:

```
items->list->dictionary->dictionary->dictionary->our targets
```

And here's how the code looks:

```
import jmespath


  data  = “””[your data above]”””

expression = jmespath.compile("items[*].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.[{publishedAt:publishedAt, textOriginal:textOriginal}]")

outcome = expression.search(data)


print(outcome)

[[{'publishedAt': '2020-06-06T09:36:04Z',
   'textOriginal': 'Nobody:\n\nMarques Brownlee: *Making everyones quarantines better*'}],
 [{'publishedAt': '2020-06-06T09:36:03Z',
   'textOriginal': 'God bless America and all the people there, no matter whether white or black. \nGreetings from an American who living in Germany for years now.'}],
 [{'publishedAt': '2020-06-06T09:35:16Z',
   'textOriginal': 'Awesome to hear you speak up!!!'}],
 [{'publishedAt': '2020-06-06T09:35:09Z', 'textOriginal': 'We hear you.'}],
 [{'publishedAt': '2020-06-06T09:34:28Z',
   'textOriginal': "Theres Nothing wrong to be Proud of being black or white or Asian and Any other race for that matter....If it makes people smile and better/more competitive in a good way then so be it.But when people get hurt or even Die:( That is Truely out or order....Times Need to change because we all Bleed Red....And even if we didn't all bleed red we Shouldn't be Hurting Them period!! We All Need to do a little soul searching and learn to value others and Life in general No Matter the Differences And thats including The Beautiful Animals on the land and seas."}],
 [{'publishedAt': '2020-06-06T09:32:35Z',
   'textOriginal': 'Would love to see your parents in video..\ud83d\ude07'}]]
```

Comment: The edits should make that clear - the problem is the txtspk abbreviations of "u" and "ur" (of which you have 101 and 88 respectively in your post history, which is a lot of damage to repair). Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.